Proof for the existence of some parameters that make functions' values linearly independent
I have a set of functions $\{F_1(x,s_1),F_2(x,s_2),\cdots, F_n(x,s_n)\}$ where each $F_i(x)$ is a nonlinear function of $s_i \in \mathbb R$ and $F_i \neq F_j$, $i \neq j$.
I was wondering how to prove that there exists a set $\{s_1',\cdots, s_n'\}$ such that $\{F_1(x,s_1'),F_2(x,s_2'),\cdots, F_n(x,s_n')\}$ with fixed $x$ are linearly independent.
I have found that I can use Wronskian matrix but I was wondering if there is another approach that is mathematically sound and yet concise. Thank you in advance!

Wronskian would require the functions to be suffciently smooth. Are they?

That's a good point. I know they are at least C^1. If they are not differentiable upto n-1, doed that mean I cant use Wronskian?

Also, are the comdomains of the $F_i$ even at least $\mathbb R^n$? And in the title, you want functions to be linearly independent, but in the question body you want their values for some (or all?) fixed $x$ linearly independent.

I now see what your comment is saying. Yeah, I want their values to be linearly independent. I edited the title accordingly. Also, I have $F_i:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$. Thank you for the help.
